# What is the OPTIMAL way to iterate through an array or string in C?

Tags: c

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252721/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-without-knowing-the-size-in-c) and a few others but none really answer my question.

Ive done:

`while ( *arr )`

`while ( *arr[i] != '\0' )`

but i don't know if there's a better way

Comment: `while ( *arr[i] != '\0' )` is only for strings

Comment: The two examples you've shown aren't the same. Also, what's wrong with `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){ /* Use arr[i] */ }` ?

Comment: Typically only strings have a terminator at the end. Some array may have terminators, which may or may not be a zero. Otherwise you use the length (number of elements) in the array in a `for` loop. Which is most "optimal"? Test it out and profile and measure!

Comment: And why do you wonder? Is this really such a bottleneck in your program (profiled and measured) that you need to find another way to iterate over arrays? Otherwise, unless this is a top-three bottleneck in your code (which it very likely isn't, not the looping in itself I mean) bothering about micro-optimizations aren't really worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is checking if the list of strings ends in a NULL pointer; the second is checking if the list of strings ends in an empty* string.

<sup>*I'm making an assumption here that `i` is zero; else this question makes no sense.</sup>

Using NULL as the terminator of a list of strings is always the faster API design both for the creator of the list and the consumer of the list.

---

Alternatively, you meant to ask if `while (*arr)` is faster or slower than `while (*arr != '\0')`. If your compiler isn't truly ancient these compile to the same thing so it makes no difference. Do whatever's easier to read.